# How to enable services Discovery API in GoogleCL?

Tags: google

There are bits and pieces of information all over the place but I'm trying to put it all together so that GoogleCL finally accesses more than the initial 7 services.  Does anyone know of a step-by-step?

Right now any attempt outside these result in the error message:

`google tasks list`

> Did you specify the service correctly? Must be one of 'picasa',
>   'blogger', 'youtube', 'docs', 'contacts', 'calendar', 'finance'

I installed GoogleCL from the Ubuntu repos, authenticated a few bundled services like contacts, docs etc. and those work great, giving me access to do certain operations like upload from the command line.

I would really like to get it going to support tasks and all the other elegible Google services shown at https://code.google.com/apis/explorer/#_s=tasks

Here are some guides/partial steps I've found:

- http://code.google.com/p/googlecl/wiki/DiscoveryManual

(indicates needing to check it out updated GoogleCL from the subversion repository.)

- http://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/wiki/Installation

`easy_install --upgrade google-api-python-client`

- http://code.google.com/p/googlecl/wiki/Install
- http://code.google.com/p/googlecl/source/checkout

  sudo -i

  cd /usr/local/src/

  svn checkout http://googlecl.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ googlecl-read-only

  cat googlecl-read-only/INSTALL.txt

  cd /usr/local/src/googlecl-read-only/

  python setup.py install

Result:

```
$ google
> discovery list
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/google", line 488, in run_interactive
    run_once(options, args)
  File "/usr/bin/google", line 540, in run_once
    options.config)
  File "/usr/bin/google", line 364, in import_service
    force_gdata_v1 = config.lazy_get(package.SECTION_HEADER,
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SECTION_HEADER'
```

Answer (score 1):

[This workaround](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/googlecl-discuss/kqzdMEDnh8k/qkAwQ70Xw7IJ) involves NOT using the .deb packaged GoogleCL:

```
/usr/local/src/googlecl-read-only/build/scripts-2.7/google tasks tasks list
```

was the alternative binary from svn that supported Services Discovery API.  The example above tests the "Google Tasks" cli which is beyond the initial seven services supported by the Ubuntu distro GoogleCL.